# set value column where id is in the other table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to modify a table of my taking the id of another table being that this other table is with another column, taking only if the data of that column is 2, take the ID of that column and use in the one that I want to change, example:

```
UPDATE QuestData SET RepeatFinish = 100000
WHERE QuestID =
(
    SELECT * FROM Quest WHERE QuestID = 2
);
```

But QuestData have so much data and table Quest too, how can i make this?

Comment: Please show the structure of your two tables *(fields names, etc, plus some example data)*.  Then, with more examples, show the actual results that you want *(so we can see if you want to update just one row, multiple rows, how the update should work, etc)*.  Also, please describe what is happening that you don't want to happen *(error messages, wrong results, etc)*.  The more information you provide, the clearer your question will be, and clear examples often best explain that...

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: I already get it with the answer below, thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE QuestData SET RepeatFinish = 100000
WHERE QuestID in
(
    SELECT id FROM Quest WHERE QuestID = 2
);
```

Change the **id** in select by yours. when using the in with an other request the select must return a one field that will be used in IN, you are using * so we don't know with what we should compare the QuestID

Comment: That's an assumption.  It feels strange that `[Quest]` would have both `id` and `QuestID` fields *(though a recursive relationship is totally possible)*.  I suspect that more than just this is wrong.  Until the OP provides the table structures you can't be sure.  You're making assumptions that the single syntax error is the *only* error.

Comment: Yeah you're are correct, and I made this assumptions just to help hem because I think the error was in the equal operator that he is using with `SELECT *`

Comment: the "id" is the column, or some data of sql to get on query?

Comment: it's your column change by the appropriate name